# Torch.ai and PyTorch - What's with the connection?

Tags: pytorch, branding

There is a ML/AI company I came across called https://Torch.ai and the logo looks exactly like the PyTorch logo. They don't mention PyTorch anywhere on the site but it looks like they should. I really thought I was missing something I should be aware of about this company and PyTorch as if they were a part of PyTorch. It's just that the logo, the name and the industry are the same. Everything else is "different."

I felt a bit misled looking all over this site trying to figure out their connection. At least that's the path I followed.

Can someone enlighten me on what I'm missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: [torch.ai](https://torch.ai) is a company in AI. [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/) is an open-source ML framework.

Comment: I do understand that part.

Comment: Not sure I follow what is troubling you? Seems strange, but that's the case. One is a framework and the other is the name of a company working in AI. They are not related since the company website doesn't even mention PytTorch being their tool.

Comment: Honestly, that is the best answer. Thanks. I conflated the two. That is all. Alrighty. Moving on.